# Push Notification using PHP in Blackberry

Tags: php, blackberry, push-notification, blackberry-webworks

I developing in Webworks and need to push a notification to the home screen when a new entry is added to our database. There is a PHP file on the server which adds entries into the database. How would I have the PHP file link to the push feature?

I have been looking at http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/How-to-Create-a-Push-BlackBerry-... to try to get an understanding of push but I am not proficient with Java for the most part so I don't understand that portion. I would ideally need to just push a number, indicating how many notifications there are. For example:

**PHP file adds 3 entries --> pushes the number "3" --> my listener.html file of the app receives the "3" and does 
blackberry.app.showBannerIndicator('images/icon.png', "3");**

I have looked at [PHP - Push Notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452779/php-push-notifications) but I don't think that's what I'm looking for. Would anyone know how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: [This forum topic](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/pushing-notifications-from-a-website-using-WebWorks/td-p/1460579) might be useful in filling in some of the gaps.

Comment: Did you come right with this i have example code if you need it

Comment: Please provide the sample..