# Send php file1 response to android immediately and then call another php file2 from file1

Tags: php, android, httprequest, httpresponse

I call file1.php from android and I want it to send xml response to android and immediately after that call file2.php from file1.php. I also want to send an array from file1.php to file2.php. How can this be done without delaying sending the response to android as android needs response only from file1. But file2 input is file1's output. So is there a way in which i can send file1's xml output to android and then call file2 immediately after that?

Details :
Android :-> Display near by restaurants using google places api.

File1.php :-> Get the list of near by restaurants google places api and send it to android.
Immediately after this I want to call File2.php from File1.php where I send the reference id's of the restaurants(o/p of File1) so that i can get each restaurants details.

Android Code:

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude",latt));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longitude", longi));

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://www.xyz.com/file1.php");

            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity      (nameValuePairs));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            line = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
```

File1.php

```
 $url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?....';
 //get xml response and send it to android

//call file2.php and send reference id's so as ot get each restaurant details
```

File2.php

```
for(each restaurant)
//get details and do some back end processing.
```

Main thing is android should receive response before file2 starts executing.

Comment: Provide more details: what is the purpose of "calling" one php file from another and how the "calling" is coded?

Comment: @Stan: Have added more details. Hope its clearer now.

Comment: Provide some code. Sounds like you need to include `file2.php` into `file1.php`, and call functions to fill in details for each item in the list before sending it to Android app.

Comment: @Stan: Code added. As far as i know include file2.php is like copy-paste of code to file1. So file1 processing = file1+file2. I don't want this as file1 takes very less time while file2 takes lot of time. And my android should not be kept on hold till file2 completes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't execute an external php-file (that is actually make a new http-request) in parallel to existing request-response flow. There exist 2 possible solutions.

1. You can implement a task queue on your server (usually a dedicated table in DB), so while processing a request by `file1.php` you should add new task in the queue. In parallel to main web-server process, you should have a php "daemon" always running, which looks for new tasks and processes them in background (fetches required details by `file2.php`). Once a task is ready (or a part of it, for example several first records with details are available), mark it appropriately in the queue. Android app should periodically check new details and load them using another access point (say `file3.php`), which returns available details from partially or completely executed task. I don't know which server-side framework do you use (if any), but some of them provide "batch jobs" based on `cron`. This looks not as easy to go way though. Most appropriate method would be to use [push notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452779/php-push-notifications), that is the server should notify your client about new available details for items in the list already sent to the client.
2. You can move part of control logic into the Android app. This way it requests a list of objects, then in a loop send new requests for object details, which are proxied to Google Places by means of `file2.php`. In other words, `file2.php` is executed by client instead of the server.

In addition, you should possibly look at some server-side tools other than php, for example [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/), which is much better suited for implementing [long polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling) and [websockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) (choose one of them).

Comment: Your explanation is very clear about the complexity of solution 1. So I am planning to go for solution 2 only. I just wanted to confirm that it's not easily possible in php.I got my answer. Thanks a ton!