# How to pass variable in real time?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a simple code:
`ajax.html`

```
<html>
<head>
<title>AJAX</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $(document).on("click", "#ajax-button", function() {
        $.ajax({type: 'POST', url: 'ajax.php', data: ({ ajax: $('input[name="ajax"]').val() }), 
                success:function(data){
                    $('#result-ajax').html(data);
                } 
        });
    });
});
</script>
<input type="text" name="ajax" /> <button id="ajax-button">OK</button>
<div id="result-ajax"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

`ajax.php`

```
<?php
$ajax = intval($_POST['ajax']);

for ($i=0; $i < $ajax; $i++) {
    echo $i;
    sleep(3); 
}
?>
```

I want get variable in real time, but now i get variable after loop, how I can update my variable in real time? I am tried set `async: false`, but it just freeze window browser.

Comment: what you mean please explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: You can't receive push notification with AJAX from your server. You should have a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452779/php-push-notifications

Comment: I want show in browser in real time variable from loop. Now i can see just last variable from loop.

Comment: OK, I understand your question now. So the answer is NO you can't do this like that because the html render is given from the server after the PHP script execution. In other words, after the loop.

Comment: The solution is to implement is to call your script regularly with a parameter (a counter for example) to return the text to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP functions as a request-response protocol, so you cant have response by the server on every 3 seconds without making new request. Another way is to use [sockets](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php). I hope its helpfull.