# Push Notifications for HTML

Tags: html, jsp, servlets, cloud

I am really new to this topic.
Scenario is I need to display messages sent by server/admin on my HTML page(could be TextArea).

Problem is i'm really new to this topic regarding servers/cloud messages/push notifications etc.. 
So first of all please guide me how can i actually access server so that admin can send push notifications and so that notifications can display on that regarding html page.
Please i'm really sorry if i'm wrong..

Comment: did you tried anything before ??

Comment: and what type of method do you like to use Push/Pull. both you can use for this you can search about these methodoligies and continue with your work.

Comment: I actually intended to display messages sent by admin from server..that is the basic thought of mine. But its getting difficult for me even to start. I am not getting any idea from where to start. please it could be helpful for me if you can provide even basic resources so that i can start my work. TIA

Comment: then I would like to suggest you visit this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452779/php-push-notifications

Comment: Yes!! Sure Thank you :)