# iOS Push implementation in PHP server

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, push-notification

How to exactly configure and implement **iOS push** notification in **PHP** server? **.Net** server need `.p12` file. But what exactly need for PHP server?

Comment: .pem file needed in PHP server

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5452792/2138791

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Export Push certificate from keychain
Go to .p12 directory in command line. Execute following

```
openssl pkcs12 -in Certificates_push_dev.p12 -out Certificates_push_dev.pem -nodes -clcerts
```

[Here](https://gist.github.com/manjeshpv/d5b8e271af94824836d9) is the **PHP Code**

Answer (score 0):

You need to create .pem certificate which you can use in your .php file including passphrase

Comment: @SolidLine when you create .p12 mac ask you to put Password to you generated .pem this called passphrase

Comment: passphrase is for security purpose, when you create .p12 certificate from Keychain Access, you can assign Password or you can keep it blank.