# auto load php script

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, autoload

I have shared folder between in my server which will allow other server to send XML file to me and I want my script read this file auto without opening any page.
I know how to open and read the file.

But the issue how to auto load in the backhand.

Comment: You will have to use something as Cron jobs (depending of your server OS), wich will call your scripts at regulars intervals.

Comment: How will the XML file be sent? Is it a matter of just checking if a file exists on a network path?

Comment: I am Windows server 2012 using IIS with PHP 7.

Comment: The file will be send via MQ

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a one page which will read the provided file and do the required actions , then share this URL and format with the team who will going to provide you the xml file.

It is very much like API Endpoint, Where you have to write the code which will handled request and in this scenario your Endpoint will treat as a server and XML file provider will treat as clients.

I hope this answer helps u.
Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's API end point and I already the page which will read the code once the folder contain one or more XML file but I have to open the page in the browser to read this file.

Comment: Do you mean I have to use like CURL method to read the file and I will use like POST ,GET ,REQUEST to handle the file from them?

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally, you need your server to [periodically execute the script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542804/best-way-to-run-scheduled-tasks) which reads the XML. That PHP will need to [parse the XML](http://www.w3schools.com/Php/php_xml_simplexml_read.asp) and handle the changes.

Alternatively, the source of the API can use [push notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452779/php-push-notifications) to avoid polling with your server. The XML will be received whenever a change occurred on the server without the creation of a lot of useless requests, but the XML will be parsed as in the previous approach.

Last, but not least, you can use [WebSockets](https://github.com/nekudo/php-websocket) for this purpose, or if both computers are in the same network, you can use sockets. Off course, a lot depends on the data source, whether you have access there, how modern is its technology and what does it allow you to do.