# apns-php error when connecting

Tags: php, ios, apple-push-notifications

Please someone help me.I have this error when connecting to apns server . The feedback works alright. It return me data.

```
Wed, 20 Apr 2011 13:14:36 +0200 ApnsPHP[30954]: INFO: Trying ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195...
Wed, 20 Apr 2011 13:14:36 +0200 ApnsPHP[30954]: ERROR: Unable to connect to 'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195': (0)
Wed, 20 Apr 2011 13:14:36 +0200 ApnsPHP[30954]: INFO: Retry to connect (1/3)...
Wed, 20 Apr 2011 13:14:37 +0200 ApnsPHP[30954]: INFO: Trying ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195...
Wed, 20 Apr 2011 13:14:38 +0200 ApnsPHP[30954]: ERROR: Unable to connect to 'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195': (0)
Wed, 20 Apr 2011 13:14:38 +0200 ApnsPHP[30954]: INFO: Retry to connect (2/3)...
Wed, 20 Apr 2011 13:14:39 +0200 ApnsPHP[30954]: INFO: Trying ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195...
Wed, 20 Apr 2011 13:14:39 +0200 ApnsPHP[30954]: ERROR: Unable to connect to 'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195': (0)
Wed, 20 Apr 2011 13:14:39 +0200 ApnsPHP[30954]: INFO: Retry to connect (3/3)...
Wed, 20 Apr 2011 13:14:40 +0200 ApnsPHP[30954]: INFO: Trying ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195...
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ApnsPHP_Exception' with message 'Unable to connect to 'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195': (0)' in /home/flavius/public_html/apns-php/ApnsPHP/Abstract.php:352
Stack trace: 
    #0 /home/flavius/public_html/apns-php/ApnsPHP/Abstract.php(295): ApnsPHP_Abstract->_connect() 
    #1 /home/flavius/public_html/apns-php/sample_push_many.php(44): ApnsPHP_Abstract->connect()
    #2 {main} thrown in /home/flavius/public_html/apns-php/ApnsPHP/Abstract.php on line 352
```

Please someone help me.Thanks.

Comment: The error message looks pretty clear. I can't seem to establish a connection to the server either (using the `https://` prefix). What is your context here? What is your question?

Comment: menage to pass this problem by using this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292247/push-notifications-server-implementation . The problem now is that i don't receive the notification and feedback the token even though the app is installed.